# Display relative date with custom format in Android

Tags: java, android, android-dateutils

I want to translate a date to human readable format. I am using [DateUtils. getRelativeDateTimeString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeDateTimeString(android.content.Context,%20long,%20long,%20long,%20int)), but this does not fit the criteria. The output I am getting looks like: 1 hour, 15 min. ago, etc.

I want to know if it is possible to change the format to:

**3m** instead of **3 min. ago**,

**1h** instead of **1 hour. 15 min. ago** etc.

using DateUtils or is there another way to do this?

To be more precise I am looking for an Android equivalent of this [angular-filter](https://github.com/wildlyinaccurate/angular-relative-date) where you can easily change the format of the relative date (for example: `{{minutes}} minutes ago` to `{{minutes}}m`.

To make myself clear, I am not searching for a way to format a date, but to translate a date to human readable format such as 'today', '1 hr', '38 min' (simillar to facebook's relative dates).

Comment: My library [Time4A](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4A) offers the class [PrettyTime](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/PrettyTime.html) for about 85 languages and different text widths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, I found out some libraries like [Time4A](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4A), [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), [PrettyTime](https://github.com/ocpsoft/prettytime), [Android-Ago](https://github.com/curioustechizen/android-ago).

However, I have decided not to use a library and override its text resources, but to create a method and store text in strings.xml for possible future localization.

```
    private static final int SECOND_MILLIS = 1000;
    private static final int MINUTE_MILLIS = 60 * SECOND_MILLIS;
    private static final int HOUR_MILLIS = 60 * MINUTE_MILLIS;
    private static final int DAY_MILLIS = 24 * HOUR_MILLIS;
    private static final int WEEK_MILLIS = 7 * DAY_MILLIS;

    public static String getTimeAgo(Date date, Context context) {
        Date now = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        final long diff = now.getTime() - date.getTime();

        if (diff < SECOND_MILLIS) {
            return context.getString(R.string.just_now);
        } else if (diff < MINUTE_MILLIS) {
            return diff / SECOND_MILLIS + context.getString(R.string.seconds_ago);
        } else if (diff < 2 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
            return context.getString(R.string.a_minute_ago);
        } else if (diff < 59 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
            return diff / MINUTE_MILLIS + context.getString(R.string.minutes_ago);
        } else if (diff < 90 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
            return context.getString(R.string.an_hour_ago);
        } else if (diff < 24 * HOUR_MILLIS) {
            return diff / HOUR_MILLIS + context.getString(R.string.hours_ago);
        } else if (diff < 48 * HOUR_MILLIS) {
            return context.getString(R.string.yesterday);
        } else if (diff < 6 * DAY_MILLIS) {
            return diff / DAY_MILLIS + context.getString(R.string.days_ago);
        } else if (diff < 11 * DAY_MILLIS) {
            return context.getString(R.string.a_week_ago);
        } else {
            return diff / WEEK_MILLIS + context.getString(R.string.weeks_ago);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you parse the Date to the format you want?

With string.replace() you can do it in one line of code.

Edit 1: I usually use SimpleDateForma this way, hope it helps:

`SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
 String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());`

you will need this imports ( i think that Android automatically imports):

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
```

Edit 2: In your example what you have to do is:

`SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH'h' mm'm'");
 String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
 System.out.println("Today in dd-MM-yy:HH:mm:SS : " + date);`

Comment: How would you parse Date object into 3 minutes ago or 1 hour ago? It's not one line of code. I am asking if there is some library or util for this.

Comment: The OP does not want to format an object of type `java.util.Date` but the delta between two objects of this type i.e. a duration. That is a big difference.

Comment: Meno Hochschild, exactly! It's called relative date or relative time.

Comment: Two facts about your solution suggested in "edit-2": `SimpleDateFormat` is not designed or suitable for printing durations => a) cannot handle field overflow (example: 25 hours), b) suffers from strange timezone effects.

Answer (score -2):

You should use [SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and specify your desired template. Which in your case would be something like this:

```
String template = "H'h', m'm'";
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(template, Locale.getDefault());
String formatted = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the built-in [DateUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeDateTimeString(android.content.Context,%20long,%20long,%20long,%20int)) utility library that was included in API level 3.

```
 CharSequence getRelativeDateTimeString (Context c, 
             long time, 
             long minResolution, 
             long transitionResolution, 
             int flags) Return string describing the elapsed time since startTime formatted like "[relative time/date], [time]".
```

Example output strings for the US date format:

> 3 min. ago, 10:15 AM Yesterday, 12:20 PM Dec 12, 4:12 AM 11/14/2007,
>   8:20 AM